# Evaluate a string of a mathematical expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems getting my equals function to work correctly is JS, it is just printing the string and now computing the equation, The input save to history feature is working but the completion of the equation is not.

JAVASCRIPT

```
  function displynum(n1){
  calcform.txt1.value=calcform.txt1.value+n1;
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.numberfunc').click(function(){
      displynum($(this).val());
    });
    $("#eqlbtn").click(function(){
      z1 = $("#txt1").val();
      $("#history").append(z1 + "<br>");
    });
  });
```

https://pastebin.com/MQj9VnaC

All my code is in the pastebin

Comment: I'm having problems understanding your description. Can you explain it in more detail? What is your "equals function"? What is "print to the history"?

Comment: Please post all you code in the pastebin/here etc.

Comment: He was actually looking to evaluate a string mathematical expression using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line as follows

```
 z1 = eval($("#txt1").val());
```

eval function evaluates the expression

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to output the entire equation in the history? e.g. '10+10 = 20' in the history.

Comment: $("#history").append($("#txt1").val() + "<br>");

Comment: @khunnaball Please accept my solution by clicking on the green tick next to it.